# Cycle differents rows in tensor by different offsets

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to build a model that does the following:

Given two time series drawn from the same underlying distribution of discrete values (in a finite cyclic group), take their element-wise difference and feed it to the model.

The model's task is to reconstruct the two original time series when only knowing their difference.

I am using cross entropy as the loss.  But I want to introduce a separate loss:

Take the predicted probabilities for the categories of the first sequence, shift them by the sequence of differences given as input, and look at the absolute difference to the probabilities predicted for the sequence.

How do I implement this in keras / tensorflow?  I already looked into `roll` and `gather`, but they don't give enough flexibility.  `gather_nd` might be workable, but not sure whether that's a good idea?

I only managed to implement this with dynamic layers so far, but that's horribly slow.

Btw, in the application I am interested in, the two sequences are English text.  I am trying to [Decrypt the Two Time Pad](https://web.archive.org/web/20120311202530/http://www.itasoftware.com/careers/puzzle_archive.html?catid=39).  I have achieved ~85% accuracy so far.  But I am trying to improve.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: `gather` takes an argument `batch_dims` that does exactly what I need.